# Is there a semaphore in Qt that is based on event loops as opposed to thread blocking?

Tags: c++, qt, semaphore, blocking, qeventloop

The threadblocking of a semaphore or a mutex often causes program stuttering, and I'd rather have one that was based on QEventLoop, where as that will not halt the thread.

Does this already exist, particularly for a semaphore, or do I need to create my own class to implement this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: I'd say that while you wait, you could manually spin the event loop, but without a little code it's just guessing